# Analyzing a Strategic Form Game for Locating a Public Facility

Tags: game-theory, economics, utility

I'm exploring a scenario where a public facility needs to be located along a street segment represented by the interval $[0, 1]$. In this setting, there are $n$ agents, each having their preferred location $p_i \in (0, 1)$ for the facility. The utility of agent $i$ is determined by the distance between their ideal location and the chosen facility location, denoted as $-|p_i - k|$, where $k$ represents the facility's location.

To decide the facility's location, a voting game is employed, where each agent $i$ casts a vote by selecting a location $x_i \in [0, 1]$. The facility's final location is determined as the average of all the votes: $$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_n}{n}$$

I'm trying to prove that no agent has a weakly dominating strategy here. I think I have understood the intuition but facing some difficulty in formally writing down the solution.
In my understanding, there are three possible cases.

#CASE_1 when $x_i < p_i$. In this case player $i$ can do better by voting something between $x_i$ and $p_i$

#CASE_2 when $p_i < x_i$. In this case player $i$ can do better by voting something between $p_i$ and $x_i$

#CASE_3 when $x_i = p_i$. In this case player $i$ can do better by voting $p_i - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is positive and arbitrarily close to zero.

We're demonstrating that each agent's utility has always been somewhat higher while playing pi than when playing any other $x_i ≠ p_i$ regardless of what the other players do.
I saw another solution where they did this by unilateral deviation such that $U(x_1, x_2, . . ., x_n) = p_i  < 0$. I failed to understand this bit.

Is the way I did it correct? If not, please help me understand where I went wrong.

Comment: I just noticed that the formula for the facility's location is probably wrong. It should be $$\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n},$$ right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made an error while posting the question. Will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are generally going in the right direction. However, your proof is not complete.

More specifically, your argument for the individual cases is not correct: For example, if player $i$ votes for $x_i \lt p_i$ (case 1), it is not necessarily true that they can improve by voting for some location in $(x_i,p_i)$ (just consider a situation where the other players voted in such a way that the outcome happens to be $p_i$ (if player $i$ votes for $x_i$). Then, voting for anything else will actually **decrease** the utility for player $i$.

However, in order to show that a strategy is not weakly dominant, you don't need to show that the player can **always** improve by deviating, anyway. It suffices to show that in **at least one situation** (=strategy profile of the other players) your player can improve by deviating.

Comment: Thank you @GraffL. I attempted this again and think I have made some more progress.

Basically, I fixed the result of votes without accounting for the $i^{th}$ player, such that 

$$[
\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}}] = p_i, \quad < p_i, \quad \text{and} \quad > p_i
$$

For each case, the $i^{th}$ player has a different strategy to maximize their utility, implying that there is no weakly dominant strategy. Does this seem right?

Comment: Another way to approach this is by contradiction, where we assume a weakly dominant strategy, say $x_i$, does exist. Then:

$$[
u_i(x_i, k) \geq u_i(x_i', k)
]$$

However, given that the utility function is $-|p_i - K|$, this inequality doesn't hold for all possible values of $K$ because the absolute value function is not linear.

Comment: Your first approach should be correct. Do you see where you use the assumption $p_i \in (0,1)$ (i.e. that $p_i$ is neither $0$ nor $1$)? That is a good way of checking whether you have understood the solution.

Comment: I don't think I can see where that assumption is used, can you please tell me.
For some reason my instructor said the first approach is not correct because 'No argument is being made.' I don't understand what he meant by that. 
Also, any particular reason you think the second approach isn't correct?

Comment: Whether or not your first approach is accepted as a solution depends of course on the way you formalized it and filled in the details. However, if you never use $p_i \in (0,1)$, then your proof cannot be complete (and very likely is just too vague/informal) as the statement is wrong without this assumption (e.g. $x_i = p_i$ is a weakly dominant strategy if $p_i=0$).
For your second approach: It is not clear to me how to extract a formal argument from this. How does "absolute value is not linear" imply "the inequality does not hold for all values"? At the very least, there are steps missing